# How to optimize calling Converter for each item when mapping big lists via AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

There is entity ExternalMaterial. It comes from external system and has ID in that system.
In my system I use Guids. So I have ExternalAIdToGuidConverter which create/get guid for each external entity.
For each external entity there is External{EntityName}IdToGuidConverter. For example, the one for material (ExternalMaterialGroupIdToGuidConverter, ExternalMaterialClassIdToGuidConverter look quite the same):

```
public class ExternalMaterialIdToGuidConverter : IValueConverter<int, Guid>
{
    ...
    public Guid Convert(int sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var result = _externalIntIdMapper.GetOrCreateMap(sourceMember); // select top 1 from mapping table. if not found ->  create new record
        result.Wait();
        return result.Result.InternalId;
    }

}
```

Now when I need to get entities with guids, I use mapping profile:

```
public class MaterialMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MaterialMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ExternalMaterial, MaterialDto>()
            .ForMember(o => o.Id, o => o.ConvertUsing<ExternalMaterialIdToGuidConverter, int>(i => i.nKey))
            .ForMember(o => o.MaterialClassId, o => o.ConvertUsing<ExternalMaterialClassIdToGuidConverter, int>(i => i.nMaterialClassLink))
            .ForMember(o => o.MaterialGroupId, o => o.ConvertUsing<ExternalMaterialGroupIdToGuidConverter, int>(i => i.nGroupLink));
            // .ForMember(otherFields)
        }
}
```

However, I have lots of entities in external systems. Now the program fires external mapping converter for each external object. I would like to optimize it, because usually I map big lists and return it. What are the ways to deal with it?

Comment: The best optimization is to completely abandon AutoMapper.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderPetrov... does it matter if the GUID is predictable? ...if not, then: `int id = 321; var guidString = $"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aa{id:0000000000}"; var guid = Guid.Parse(guidString);` (assuming the foreign `id` really *is* an `int`)

Comment: unfortunately, it does matter. So it should be generated randomly

Comment: How would you do it without AM?